# Showing NOAA ENC Charts on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml, noaa

I am currently invested in a project to implement marine charts and maps into our custom Google Maps application. However, I am quite unsure of how to actually go about doing this. I would like to use the NOAA ENC data from here:

```
http://www.charts.noaa.gov/ENCs/ENCs.shtml
```

What I would like to do is use this data to display the charts on Google Maps. Does anyone have any ideas/tips/insight on how to do this?

Comment: What is your specific problem?  Are you unsure how to make a custome tile map, unsure how to cut their images into tiles, or what?  Which step in the process is giving you problems?

Comment: Basically my dilemma is that I am unsure of how to go about getting that data into Google Maps, like they have here: http://marine.geogarage.com/routes. The data is actually in electronic format, however (S-57 to be exact), but I don't know how to convert that into a format that I can import into Google Maps.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there is an open-source reader which plugs into common utility (ogr2ogr) which allows you to convert the data into shapefile format:
   http://home.gdal.org/projects/s57/

Once you get the data into shapefile format, then turning it into tiles is a well-understood problem.  Here is one blog posting of one way someone did it:
    <del>http://jongyulin.com/2009/05/getting-started-with-map-tiling-mapnik-and-shapefiles/</del>  https://web.archive.org/web/20150523144053/http://jongyulin.com:80/2009/05/getting-started-with-map-tiling-mapnik-and-shapefiles/

Comment: Cool tool, I have used it before for converting shapefiles, but didn't realize it supported S-57 files. It will also convert these ENC files directly into KML (but at least the file I tested is too big for Google Maps to display).

Comment: Does that answer your question, then?

Comment: It definitely helps! As it turns out, though, I was able to use the ogr2ogr utility to convert the files to KML, but the output files were in excess of 10 MBs each. 

I have not tried converting them to shapefiles, however, so I think I might get that together and give it a try. Thanks for all the help guys!